# Can react js site be automated with robot framework?

Tags: java, reactjs, robotframework

I was looking to find whether my react js single page application can be automated for testing using robot framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try to combine Robot Framework as test automation framework with [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org) (as web automation driver).

Step 1. Configure Selenium drivers for your browsers ([IE driver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), [Firefox driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), [Chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)) by putting these browser drivers to the PATH variable on the machine. Otherwise, you can use [Selenium Grid and virtualise everything with Docker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium), but that is more complicated.

Step 2. Connect Robot Framework with Selenium. You can do that with a library inside RF, called [SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary). This allows for RF to recognise the different keywords/functions of Selenium, and by using them to connect to a browser using a Selenium driver, or the Selenium Grid.

The steps above are valid for all types of webpages, not only ReactJS.